# How to execute many process tests in Mocha?

Tags: javascript, mocha.js

I have a repo with ~70 test of executables. When running under [mocha](https://travis-ci.org/shexSpec/shex.js/jobs/381272325#L473) or [jest](https://travis-ci.org/shexSpec/shex.js/jobs/384510431#L6240), it typically gets either errors on the first couple promises, either because of a timeout or because stdout never made it back to the parent process.

My minimal replication of this problem involves 100 threads, each calling a command line which sleeps for 10s:

```
let child_process = require('child_process');
let AllTests = [];

/* start processes */
for (let i = 0; i < 100; ++i) {
  AllTests.push({
    i: i,
    start: new Date(),
    exec: new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let program = child_process.spawn(
        'node', ['-e', 'setTimeout(() => { process.exit(0); }, 9999)'])
        // 'node', ['-e', 'for (let i = 0; i < 2**28; ++i) ;'])
      program.on('exit', exitCode => { resolve({exitCode:exitCode}) })
      program.on('error', err => { reject(err) })
    })
  })
}

/* test results */
describe('churn', () => {
  AllTests.forEach(test => {
    it('should execute test ' + test.i + '.',
       done => {
         test.exec.then(exec => {
           test.end = new Date()
           done()
         })
       })
  })
})
```

On my under-powered laptop, I typically get:

```
  93 passing (19s)
  7 failing

  1) churn
       should execute test 0.:
     Error: Timeout of 2000ms exceeded. For async tests and hooks, ensure "done()" is called; if returning a Promise, ensure it resolves. (/home/eric/errz/flood.js)
  ...
```

Adding some accounting afterwards:

```
after(() => {
  console.log()
  AllTests.forEach(test => {
    console.log(test.i, (test.end - test.start)/1000.0)
  })
})
```

shows that each process takes ~19s.

Given that this occurs in Mocha and Jest, I guess that the issue is related to the 100 simultaneous processes. Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could almost address the timeouts and the stdio stream issues separately.
The stream issues mostly cleared up when I pushed the exit-handler for process termination into the next event cycle:

```
program.on("exit", function(exitCode) {
  setTimeout(
    () => resolve({stdout:stdout, stderr:stderr, exitCode:exitCode}), 0
  )
});
program.on("error", function(err) { reject(err); });
```

The timeouts were because I was flooding the process table.
Rather than getting overly intimate with the kernel's scheduler, I used [timeout-promise-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeout-promise-queue), which throttled the total concurrent processes and provided timeouts based on the start time of each queued process.

Using [timeout-promise-queue](https://www.npmjs.com/package/timeout-promise-queue) also cleared up the malingering stream issues, which only showed up when the process table got too large.
After thousands of tests, I settled on a process queue of 25 and a 0-length timeout on the exit-handler.

The [resulting diffs](https://github.com/shexSpec/shex.js/commit/80d715bc7a8753d6ff6bcaf34ff94d4e37311dee#diff-4b704b373a591b75fa93036c2f681941) are pretty minimal and self-explanatory and I no longer have to hit [↻Restart job] on [Travis tests](https://travis-ci.org/shexSpec/shex.js/jobs/386146935#L791).